# Checking for maximum value in list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program that scores scrabble games and I am working on the end that will tell which player won by looping through the list of scores and names that looks similar to this.

```py
players = [[john, 6], [bill, 13], [samantha, 6], [james, 2]]
```

I have tried a few ideas, but to be honest, I have no idea in what direction to go in this situation.  I want the function to return `Player  has the highest score!` but if there is a tie, it would return `Player {name1} and player {name2} had a tie`, and if there are any higher ties, like a three way tie, it would just loop through and return `Player {name} has a score of {score}` for each player.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just show you an example of printing person with highest score. I place them in a list (numlist) first to determine the highest, get the index and retrieve them from the original list.

```
numlist = []
players = [["john", 6], ["bill", 13], ["samantha", 6], ["james", 2]]
for items in players:
    numlist.append(items[1])
numlist.index(max(numlist))  #getting index of highest number
print("Highest score of " + str(max(numlist)) + " goes to " + str(players[1][0]) + " !")
```

This outputs:

```
Highest score of 13 goes to bill!
```

If you want to get ties, without 3 or more, you can implement this:

This function to get repeated elements in list is cited from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-print-duplicates-list-integers/:

```
def Repeat(x):
    _size = len(x)
    repeated = []
    for i in range(_size):
        k = i + 1
        for j in range(k, _size):
            if x[i] == x[j] and x[i] not in repeated:
                repeated.append(x[i])
    return repeated
```

Then followed by,

```
donecount = []
tielist = (Repeat(numlist))
for values in numlist:
    if values in donecount:
        continue
    if (numlist.count(values) == 2):
        tieindex = [index for index, value in enumerate(numlist) if value == values]
        print("Tie goes to " + str(players[tieindex[0]][0]) + " and " + str(players[tieindex[1]][0]) +" with the score " + str(values))
        donecount.append(values)
```

Should get you an output of:

```
Tie goes to john and samantha with the score 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
players = [["john", 6], ["bill", 13], ["samantha", 6], ["james", 2]]
min = ["dummy", 0 ]
for player in players:
    if player[1] > min[1]:
        min = player
print( min )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to use the `max` function. This function accepts a `key` parameter which can be used for the comparisons, just like `sorted` does.

```py
>>> players = [['john', 6], ['bill', 13], ['samantha', 6], ['james', 2]]
>>> name, score = max(players, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> name
'bill'
>>> score
13
```

If you want to find all of the players with this score (in case of ties), you can use a list comprehension:

```py
>>> [p for p in players if p[1] == score]
[['bill', 13]]
```

In this case the result only has Bill in it, but if other players had the same score they would be in there too.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do what you want:

```
import io

def arg_max(container):
    """
    Returns the indices of the maximum elements
    For example,
        arg_max([1, 1, 9, 2, 9])
    returns
        [2, 4]
    """
    it = iter(container)
    max_indices = [0]
    _max = next(it)
    for idx, elem in enumerate(it, 1):
        if elem == _max:
            max_indices.append(idx)
        elif elem > _max:
            _max = elem
            max_indices = [idx]

    return max_indices

def create_endgame_message(player_scores):
    # if player_scores ==
    #     [["john", 6], ["bill", 13], ["samantha", 6], ["james", 2]]
    # then scores ==
    # [6, 13, 6, 2]
    scores = [score for name, score in player_scores]
    winnies  = list(arg_max(scores))
    print(winnies)
    with io.StringIO() as string_stream:
        nwinners = len(winnies)
        if nwinners == 1:
            player_name = player_scores[winnies[0]][0]
            print(
                player_name, "had the highest score!",
                file=string_stream
            )
        elif nwinners == 2:
            player_name1 = player_scores[winnies[0]][0]
            player_name2 = player_scores[winnies[1]][0]
            print(
                player_name1, " and ", player_name2,
                "tied for winning place",
                file=string_stream
            )
        elif nwinners >= 3:
            for winny in winnies:
                player_name  = player_scores[winny][0]
                player_score = player_scores[winny][1]
                print(
                    player_name,
                    "had a score of",
                    player_score,
                    file=string_stream
                )
        msg = string_stream.getvalue()
    return msg

player_scores = [["john", 6], ["bill", 13], ["samantha", 6], ["james", 2]]
print(create_endgame_message(player_scores))
```